# Compare two PyInstaller generated Linux executables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

The problem is quite simple, but I don't see any sample.

I need to compare two executables generated by PyInstaller and determine which one is newer (but not by simple timestamp). Timestamp might be newer, but the content stays the same. I need to replace the old file only if both timestamp is newer and the content is different.

Any example solution? For example simple version tag in PyInstaller (strange but can't find much info on it, in manual it says only about using Windows version files)

update:

- Linux executables
- Have access to files generation process.
- it is cli app and best is not to use vcs, some simple solution.
- actual comparison process will take place in a Python script
- tried `filecmp` as suggested - it returns `False` even for the same build generated 2 times (with `shallow=False` flag).

Best option as to my point of view is to compare content & timestamp. if timestamp is newer and the content is different => means new version.

Comment: Tried filecmp? https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html

Comment: Do you have access to how the files are generated?

Comment: Are you building the executables?  What OS are you using?  Is the a CLI or GUI App?  Are you using a VCS for your project?

Comment: Use BeyondCompare.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: BTW downvoting wasn't fare, all of this questions were initially answered in topic itself / init. description.

Comment: BeyondCompare runs on Linux and has an API you can call from Python.

Comment: What is the precise definition of "newer" that you have in mind? Without that, it's like asking "what is better", it just can't be answered.

Comment: i think that the definition of "newer" is quite clear from the context. If you normally need to write a page of very precise definitions and contextual information to explain a few phrases for example - that is very ineffective way of communication.

Answer (score 5):

When you run `pyinstaller`, you have to ensure that you perform a *reproducible* build. i.e one that can be used to perform a bit for bit comparison between executables. According to the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#creating-a-reproducible-build):

> Python uses a random hash to make dicts and other hashed types, and this affects compiled byte-code as well as PyInstaller internal data structures. As a result, two builds may not produce bit-for-bit identical results even when all the components of the application bundle are the same and the two applications execute in identical ways.

To do this, just set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to a constant number before running `pyinstaller`:

```
PYTHONHASHSEED=1
export PYTHONHASHSEED
pyinstaller --onefile test.py

unset PYTHONHASHSEED
```

Then you can use whatever tools/modules you want to compare the executables, such as `filecmp`, BeyondCompare etc., or even just a simple checksum in linux:

```
cksum dist/test
```

---

**EDIT**: With regards to timestamping or tagging a binary - you could do the following to add additional notes to a linux binary after its built:

```
# Create a file with the notes or comments to add to the binary. 
# I am adding the current date for versioning info
date > version

# Add notes to the binary
objcopy --add-section .pyversion=version --set-section-flags .pyversion=noload,readonly dist/test dist/test-with-version

# Check the version/notes on the new binary
objdump -sj .pyversion dist/test-with-version
```

You should get something like:

```
dist/test-with-version:     file format elf64-x86-64
Contents of section .pyversion:
0000 46726920 53657020 31342031 343a3339  Fri Sep 14 14:39
0010 3a333620 41455354 20323031 380a      :36 AEST 2018.
```

Comment: Nice!  You could also add a timestamp string into the python and spit it back out with a command line argument.